# Add Imageviews dynamically inside the circle which is already drawn on google map in android

Tags: android

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

If you observe the above two pictures, **there are markers in picture1, if user tap on marker second picture will come with available options dynamically may be 2,3 etc.**

For the second picture I have written custom view and able to draw circle but unable to show images inside the circle.

```
      public class CustomView extends ViewGroup {

    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // create the Paint and set its color
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xFF1f5b83);
    }


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = this.getWidth();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2-64, 200, paint);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

}
```

For testing purpose I am adding text instead of image

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
    circleView = new CustomView(this);



    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Test");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    addContentView(circleView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    circleView.bringToFront();

}
```

How to add images inside the circle in Java class I mean Activity class?

Comment: Have you thought about using an `ImageView` and toggling the visibility when necessary?

Comment: @vguzzi 13,  its not only toggling an image, I need to display dynamic data inside the image as well (I mean inside the circle if it is image)